# Inquiry about some features of classes in ruby

Tags: ruby

im new to ruby and currently reading a book. After reading the section i made my own example and still a bit confused

```
class Operation
  def multiply(a,b)
    @result = a*b
  end
  def get_multiply
    return @result
  end
  def divide(a,b)
    @dividend = a / b
    return dividend
  end
end 

my_operation = Operation.new
my_operation.multiply(5,6)
puts my_operation.get_multiply
```

Is there any difference between my code and simply scrapping the `get_multiply` method and return `@result` after we set it to `a*b`. Also if I take out the `@` sign on result my code still works. In the book it says this is an instance variable. My question is, whats the point of `@` really?

This code here still works

```
class Operation
  def multiply(a,b)
    result = a*b
  end
  def get_multiply
    return result
  end
  def divide(a,b)
    @dividend = a / b
    return dividend
  end
end 

my_operation = Operation.new
puts my_operation.multiply(5,6)
```

Comment: “My question is, whats the point of @ really?”—It is an instance variable.

Comment: Yes, it said that in the book. But if I take out the @ symbols my code still works. Why did they use it here?

Comment: No, if you take out `@` your code won’t work. Namely, `puts my_operation.get_multiply` will print nothing.

Comment: If you remove @ in `get_multiply` method ruby will produce error (undefined local variable or method)

Comment: i think he means to scrape `get_multiply` method and use `multiply` method only directly.

Comment: yes thats what I did ^ sorry

Comment: @HarshTrivedi Yes, but he must remove the method. Bcs. If he call `get_multiply` directlly, the error will be generated.

Comment: Your `divide` code doesn't work, because `dividend` and `@dividend` are different things and the former isn't assigned any value.

Comment: Yea true, but he is calling `multiply` method and saying that it's working. Rather than `get_multiply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` symbol is used to persist the variable for later use. From this examples, it's' difficult to understand the importance of it. There is also `@@` symbol for class variable - but I won't go in that for now.

In your code `multiply` method is playing the role of storing (probably for later use) and `get_multiply` is used to retrieve what was stored.

If you scrape `get_multiply` and use `multiply` directly - fair enough. Things will work. But you will now not have option to do some computation early, store it and retrieve it directly when required.

Hope it has helps : )

Comment: Could you see my edit. It still works without it @, in that case

Comment: Ok. This is what I have understood: If you dont put @. And you try to use the same variable you attached @ to in another method. You won't be able to since it isnt defined there? Is that correct/

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What you have done in your edit is: scraped out `get_multiply ` (it's not being used at all). You are only using `multiply` directly without storing the results and using it later. Get it ?

Comment: What programming laguage background you come from? I can try to give you an analogy.

Comment: If you don't put @ before variable say `result` instead of `@result`, then the variable will not be accessible from other methods: like `result` of multiply will not be accessible in `get_multiply`. Got it ?

Comment: beauty. exactly what I suspected. Thanks alot

Comment: M really glad it helped. I would suggest that you search a little on `class` and `instance` variables and `methods` in ruby. JS and PHP are difficult to give analogy in as they are not fully class based object oriented. If you really want to learn ruby, I suggest you watch this course once: https://www.lynda.com/Ruby-tutorials/essential-training/47905-2.html?srchtrk=index:1%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq:ruby%2Bessential%2Btraining%0Apage:1%0As:relevance%0Asa:true%0Aproducttypeid:2

Comment: By the way it seems that method is used here, where in javascript we generally call it a function. But call types set to functions, a method. In Ruby do we call anything a "function"?

Comment: functions in ruby are called methods.

Comment: interesting. Thanks

Comment: By the way just got the videos for that course, I'll take a course. Is it a good course?